# JPanel and custom Class extending JPanel not displaying correctly

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I came across a slight bug when extracting hefty parts of code from my main GUI class and putting them into smaller manageable classes.

So I did another test with a very simple GUI and found that the same bug happens there even though the only difference is that the code is in a different location.

The first JPanel displays correctly and fills the entire layout.
The second TestPanel that extends JPanel does not display correctly and fills a very small portion of the layout.

[image: The working JPanel containing JScrollPane with a JTextArea in it's viewport]
[image: The non working JPanel containing JScrollPane with a JTextArea in it's viewport]

Both classes have exactly the same GridBagLayout and both JScrollPanes have the same GridBagConstraints.

Here is my main class with an JTabbedPane containing two JPanels containing one JScrollPane each with a JTextArea in it's viewport.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestMainGUI
{
    private JFrame frame;
    private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    private JPanel workingDefaultPanel;
    private JScrollPane workingDefaultScrollPane;
    private JTextArea workingDefaultJTextArea;
    private TestJPanel notWorkingExtendingJPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    TestMainGUI window = new TestMainGUI();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public TestMainGUI()
    {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //******************************************************************//
        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(SwingConstants.TOP);
        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //******************************************************************//
        workingDefaultPanel = new JPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Working Panel", null, workingDefaultPanel, null);
        GridBagLayout gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        workingDefaultPanel.setLayout(gbl_WorkingDefaultPanel);
        //******************************************************************//
        workingDefaultScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
        workingDefaultPanel.add(workingDefaultScrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);
        //******************************************************************//
        workingDefaultJTextArea = new JTextArea();
        workingDefaultScrollPane.setViewportView(workingDefaultJTextArea);
        //******************************************************************//
        notWorkingExtendingJPanel = new TestJPanel();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Non Working Panel", null, notWorkingExtendingJPanel, null);
        GridBagLayout gbl_panel_1 = new GridBagLayout();
        gbl_panel_1.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gbl_panel_1.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gbl_panel_1.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        notWorkingExtendingJPanel.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);
    }
}
```

and here is my TestJPanel

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class TestJPanel extends JPanel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5041143050449865233L;
    private JScrollPane notWorkingJScrollPane;
    private JTextArea notWorkingJTextArea;

    public TestJPanel()
    {
        super();
        notWorkingJScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_notWorkingScrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_notWorkingScrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_notWorkingScrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_notWorkingScrollPane.gridy = 0;
        this.add(notWorkingJScrollPane, gbc_notWorkingScrollPane);
        //******************************************************************//
        notWorkingJTextArea = new JTextArea();
        notWorkingJScrollPane.setViewportView(notWorkingJTextArea);
    }

    protected JScrollPane getNotWorkingJScrollPane()
    {
        return notWorkingJScrollPane;
    }

    protected JTextArea getNotWorkingJTextArea()
    {
        return notWorkingJTextArea;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
notWorkingExtendingJPanel.setLayout(gbl_panel_1);
```

I would guess the problem is that you can't set the layout AFTER you add the components to the panel.

The above statement and all the grid bag layout logic should be in your TestJPanel class where you create and add the components to the panel.

Comment: Problem solved. Did not know that the order of setting the layout of a panel affected inner components.

Comment: @jordandap, the layout manager, not the panel, manages the constraints. If you change the layout manager after adding the components then you must manually add the constraints by using the `addLayoutComponent(...)` method of the `LayoutMmanager2` interface. Or, as I already suggested, the easier approach is to set the layout manager before adding the components.